# What does TCPSocket#each iterate over in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm not too familiar with Ruby, so I wasn't able to find the documentation for this method.

When calling each on a TCPSocket object, like this

```
require "socket"

srv = TCPServer.new("localhost", 7887)
skt = srv.accept
skt.each {|arg| p arg}
```

Does the block get called once per tcp packet, once per line (after each '\n' char), once per string (after after each NUL/EOF), or something different entirely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR `TCPSocket.each` will iterate for each newline delimited `\n` string it receives.

More details:

A `TCPSocket` is just a `BasicSocket` with some extra powder sugar on top. And a `BasicSocket` is a child of [`IO`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html) class. The `IO` class is just a stream of data; thus, it is iterable. And [that is where](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-i-each) you can find how `each` is defined for `TCPSocket`.

Fire up an `irb` console and enter your line of code with the `$stdin` socket to see how `each` behaves. They both inherit from `IO`. Here is an example of what happens:

```
irb(main):011:0> $stdin.each {|arg| p arg + "."}
hello
"hello\n."
```

But to directly answer the question, the block is called once per `\n` character. If your client is sending data 1 character at a time then the block is not going to be executed until it sees the `\n`.

Here is a quick sample client to show this:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'socket'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> s = TCPSocket.open("localhost", 7887)
=> #<TCPSocket:fd 9>
irb(main):003:0> s.puts "hello"
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> s.write "hi"
=> 2
irb(main):008:0> s.write ", nice to meet you"
=> 18
irb(main):009:0> s.write "\n"
=> 1
```

And here is what the server printed out:

```
"hello\n"
"hi, nice to meet you\n" # note: this did not print until I sent "\n"
```

Comment: Also note that the separator can be passed as an argument (e.g. `thing.each(sep="\r\n")`), or set for `IO#each` along with a few other methods by setting `$/`, the global default separator, which, unless changed, defaults to `\n`.

Comment: Great answer, but I'm confused by the last sentence: If I send 1 byte/packet over a TCP stream, then the input would be buffered until the byte is  '\n' and only then passed to the block, right?

Comment: That is correct @Benno , the input would be buffed until the byte is `'\n'`. **Then** the `each` block will execute. Unless you change that default behavior as Linuxios noted.